# where to point a route once user log in using FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i am using `FOSUserBundle` and i have created and activated the user now when i log in 
using following url

```
http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/login
```

[image]

i am getting following erro for it , i dont know why is this happening

here is my routes, it seems its pointing to `DefaultController` but i dont know where `FOSUSerBundle` supposed to point after login

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }

_demo_secured:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php"
    type:     annotation

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /demo

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/WSChat.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /chat

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/OpenPubSub.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /pubusb  

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple routes that you have defined with the same name `_demo` .

Regarding `FOSUserBundle` you can configure the login redirect from the `security.yml`.

```
form_login:
   provider: fos_userbundle
   csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
   always_use_default_target_path: true
   default_target_path: /
```

The `default_target_path` is where you will need to specify the url where the user should be redirected to on successful login.

Comment: okay so FOSUserBundle hasn;t given any default template and therefore we need to configure our own page rite ?

Comment: it has given default templates for login, registration , profile etc pages and yes there are ways to override those templates as well

Comment: No. It redirects to the route '/' by default